# jQuery post function for form validation only allows alert() to show returned data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, alert

Okay, so I've tried pretty much everything.

```
$.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "workbookNumber", wbn: $("input[name='wbn']").val() }, function(data) {
    error.push("<li>"+data+"</li>");
    alert(data);
});
```

The error.push is the error array that's been created, it works perfectly but it does not add to the array at all.  It's as if that line of code does not exist.  There have been instances in the comma variable data where there is an extra comma, showing it is there but even so, the `<li></li>` should still show.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/ajax.php",
    dataType:"html",
    data: { type: "workbookNumber", wbn: $("input[name='wbn']").val() },
    success:function(response) {
    alert(response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("damn. -_-");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }    
});
```

I can't think of any reasonable explanation for this, I was thinking that the PHP doesn't have enough time to show the result as it's searching through a database of over 20000 codes however, the result still comes back through the alert, just not through the error array in actual text that can be shown on screen.

The error array works fine, it's just this function that doesn't work.  Here's some other examples of what DOES work correctly:

```
if($("input[name='fname']").val() == "") {
    error.push("<li>The first name field is blank</li>");
}
if($("input[name='lname']").val() == "") {
    error.push("<li>The last name field is blank</li>");
}

if($("select[name='usertype']").val() == 0) {
    if($("input[name='vcode']").val() == "") {
        error.push("<li>The voucher code field is blank</li>");
    } else {
        $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "findVoucher", vcode: $("input[name='vcode']").val() }, function(data) {
            if(data == "none") {
                error.push("<li>The voucher code does not exist</li>");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the whole code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sit_date").datepicker();
$("select[name='usertype']").change(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="0") {
        $(".indv").slideUp(500);
        $(".comp").slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $(".indv").slideDown(500);
        $(".comp").slideUp(500);
    }
});
$("input[name='marka'],input[name='markb']").bind("keypress paste keyup  blur focus", function() {
    var marka = $("input[name='marka']").val();
    var markb = $("input[name='markb']").val();
    var perc = (marka/markb)*100;
    if(perc>0 && perc<=100) {
        $("#per").html(Math.round(perc));
    } else {
        $("#per").html("");
    }
});
$("input[name='vcode']").bind("keypress keyup paste blur focus", function() {
    $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "checkVoucher", vcode: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        $("input[name='group']").val(data);
    });
    $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "checkType", vcode: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        $("input[name='certificates']").val(data);
    });
});

$("input[name='wbn']").bind("keypress keyup paste blur focus", function() {
    $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "getAssessment", wbn: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
        if(data!="") {
            $("select[name='assessment']").html(data);
        }
    });
});

/*
//turn into function
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        alert("works");
        $("input[name='manual_add']").click();
    }
});
*/

var error = [];
$("input[name='manual_add']").click(function() {
    if($("input[name='fname']").val() == "") {
        error.push("<li>The first name field is blank</li>");
    }
    if($("input[name='lname']").val() == "") {
        error.push("<li>The last name field is blank</li>");
    }

    if($("select[name='usertype']").val() == 0) {
        if($("input[name='vcode']").val() == "") {
            error.push("<li>The voucher code field is blank</li>");
        } else {
            $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "findVoucher", vcode: $("input[name='vcode']").val() }, function(data) {
                if(data == "none") {
                    error.push("<li>The voucher code does not exist</li>");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    if($("input[name='wbn']").val() == "") {
        error.push("<li>The workbook number field is blank</li>");
    } else {

        $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "workbookNumber", wbn: $("input[name='wbn']").val() }, function(data) {
            error.push("<li>"+data+"</li>");
            //this is the only thing that works correctly:
            alert(data);
        });

    }

    if(($("input[name='questions']").val() == "") && ($("input[name='marka']").val() != $("input[name='markb']").val())) {
        error.push("<li>The questions wrong field is blank</li>");
    }

    var list = "";
    $.each(error, function(i,val) { 
        list += val;
    }); 

    if(error.length>0) {
        $(".error").slideUp(500);
        $(".jquery-error ul").html("").append(list);
        $(".jquery-error").slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: where is this error array declared?

Comment: Just after they click the button to have it all validated: var error = [];

Comment: Where are you using this error array, inside the callback or is it used after the ajax function, which of course is asynchronous? I think we need some more code.

Comment: @OliverTappin This sounds like a scoping problem, it sounds like you declared `error` inside a function and you are trying to access it after the function has finished executing. To test this theory, try declaring `var error = [];` in the global scope, or change all your references to `error` so they reference `window.error` instead, and see if that fixes it (N.B. if you use `window.error` don't use the `var` keyword when you initialise it) (N.B. **this is not a permanent fix**, just testing a theory)

Comment: Tried moving the `var error = [];` outside the function, and removing the `var` from the beginning, neither worked.  I'm not sure that's the problem as the error handling works fine, it's just the function for the workbook number (wbn) which comes back with a result from the ajax.php but only allows it to be shown within an alert() rather than within the error handling.

Comment: And just tried the `window.error` and nothing's changed.

Comment: What is the response from your server? Nothing if all went well and an error message if something wasn't correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var error` is declared in your `click()` function and is thus not accessible outside that function. Declare it globally and your code should work. (Worked fine for me on jsfiddle with a global `error` variable.)

The rest of your error handling code works fine, because it is defined in the same scope as your `error` variable (the `click()` function). But the callback to your ajax request is not executed in the context of your function, but in the `window` context. This is definitely a scope issue.

Of course you have to wait for the response from the server to come back to update your error notifications. Write a function that iterates over the `error` array and displays the corresponding notifications and then call that function from the `error` function of your AJAX call.

Try the following:

```
var error = [];

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "include/ajax.php",
    dataType:"html",
    data: { type: "workbookNumber", wbn: $("input[name='wbn']").val() },
    success:function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        error.push("<li>"+thrownError+"</li>");
        showErrors();
    }    
});​

function showErrors () {
     var list = "";
    $.each(error, function(i,val) { 
        list += val;
    }); 

    if(error.length>0) {
        $(".error").slideUp(500);
        $(".jquery-error ul").html("").append(list);
        $(".jquery-error").slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly the same as the usual `$.post` function I used.  The alert() comes up successfully with the result, but it does not add it to the array.

Comment: The difference is that the `error`variable is defined globally and that the update of the error notifications is done only after the server has responded to your AJAX call.

Comment: The `showErrors()` function wouldn't work anyway, just tested it and worked as expected, the ajax function comes back with a successful result, no errors whatsoever. Therefore the `showError()` function will not work and the array will not be displayed.

Comment: That's why I asked what the response form your server is. Then I can modify the function accordingly for you.

Comment: @Oliver Tappin Read the answer carefully, apart from the global variable that you need, you also need to check for the error length *after* all ajax calls have returned their results, in your code it is at the end of the `click` handler and that is too soon.

Comment: I do read the answers very carefully. The response from the server is quite simply 'This workbook number does not exist.' so it can be easily added to the list of errors.  Of course other variables may show depending on the input but the code you have written above shows the function `showErrors() {` around the listing of the array.  This will not list unless there is an error with the AJAX function.  Do you mean for this to be put in the success function?

Comment: Tried this with the `showError()` function within the success function and wrapped the `function showError() {` around the whole error display like so: `function showErrors() {
   var list = "";
      $.each(error, function(i,val) { 
          list += val;
      });
      if(error.length>0) {
          $(".error").slideUp(500);
          $(".jquery-error ul").html("").append(list);
          $(".jquery-error").slideDown(500);
      } else {
          $("form").submit();
      }
     }` and it worked!  Thank you very much for all your answers.  All a great help.

Comment: I simply modified your example so it would work. As I said, I didn't know what your server responds with. I assumed it might give an HTTP error if the values are incorrect, as you had implemented the `error()` function. The more important information at this point is, what does your server respond with on success (no form errors)?

Comment: The only part I need to worry about now is how to get the whole form to validate without the workbook number being the last one.  I think I'll just have to add in the `if($("input[name='wbn']").val() == "") {` within the PHP so that the function can be the very last thing to check (as all users NEED a workbook number).

Comment: Yes, but at the moment, even if the server doesn't find an error in your form data, it's response is added to the `error` array, and thus the form can never be submitted, as the `error.length>0` comparison always evaluates to true.

Comment: This is true. I could remove the data from the array if the jQuery validates it against a 'correct' response within the `showErrors()` function.

Comment: Exactly, that was my point all along... ;) Or alternatively you only ever call the `showErrors()` function if you don't get a correct answer. Otherwise you just submit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until the ajax function is completed, something like:

```
} else { //use a variable for ajax
    var XHR = $.post("include/ajax.php", { type: "workbookNumber", wbn: $("input[name='wbn']").val() }, function(data) {
        error.push("<li>"+data+"</li>");
    });

}

XHR.always(function() { //make sure ajax is completed and array updated first
    var list = "";
    $.each(error, function(i,val) { 
        list += val;
    }); 

    if(error.length>0) {
        $(".error").slideUp(500);
        $(".jquery-error ul").html("").append(list);
        $(".jquery-error").slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think `XHR.always` is a little overkill if you only want to display errors for form validation. He could be making 100's of other AJAX calls, that then all call this function.

Comment: Just tried this, and unfortunately it did not fix the problem.  The alert() comes up with the result from the AJAX request but the error array does not come up at all.

Comment: @chucktator - actually, the `always` function only works for the variable XHR that contains exactly one ajax function, not all of them. On that one ajax function you can then call `done`, `always` and `fail`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not hiding the global variable **error** with a local one. Try using

```
console.log(data);
console.log(error);
```

inside your anonymus function and you'll see where your problem is.

Comment: The console.log comes back ask this: `The workbook number does not exist.
manual.js:128["<li>The first name field is blank</li>", "<li>The last name field is blank</li>", "<li>The voucher code field is blank</li>", "The workbook number does not exist."]` so the alert shows, and the array is intact, with the data I need! However, the actual error list that shows on screen shows everything but 'The workbook number does not exist'.

Comment: Okay, so using this, I have found that the `error.push(data)` works correctly, but when it comes to showing the errors on screen, it shows everything but the workbook one.  Again, seems like a timing issue but I've tried all of that. Hmmmm.

Comment: How do you output the error array on your screen after your ajax request?

Comment: If you think it's a timig issue just try using setTimeout(function(){/*CODE*/},100); and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that the other day around the last but which adds all the errors together, did not work. Any other suggestions where to put it?

And I output the errors like this:

`var list = "";
     $.each(error, function(i,val) { 
         list += val;
     });
     if(error.length>0) {
         $(".error").slideUp(500);
         $(".jquery-error ul").html("").append(list);
         $(".jquery-error").slideDown(500);
     } else {
         $("form").submit();
     }`

Comment: Seems fine. Do you do this procedure again after you receive the responce from the ajax?

Comment: You have to do it multiple times to be able to see the result after the ajax call. You have to do it after each ajax call. If this does not help, then it's beyond me...